# How to get source?

Tags: jwplayer

https://malimar.tv/channels/5699?grid=LiveTV_PremiumHD_CF How to get the source of this site ?

Answer (score 1):

If your are using Firefox you can install the Web Developer Toolbar add-on: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/

It has an option to show the *generated* source of a web page.

Alas, to see the source of the Flash animation is a lot harder.

Comment: I get only secure token link how to get the source of the it

Answer (score 1):

if you mean the source video stream it's this http://liveplay3.malimarcdn.com/hdliveedge00/rasmeyhd.stream/media_w32412488_4775.ts?token=rasmeyhd.stream-1429407013000-3e97cb3cbjc900h3-b29add4aaac866956e642e3286808860

just fire up your developer console and monitor the network

Comment: I had tried on this way but it seem the link updated by secure token . How can i get that if still like this ?

Comment: Which part of "secure" do you not understand? It's got a token on it to prevent you from grabbing the source. You're asking us how to steal someone else's content.

Comment: ^ Yeah - StackOverFlow is a place for solving programming questions - not a place to learn how to steal content.